# Does webapplication folder name have to be webapp in java spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring framework now and curious naming convention. Is there a naming convention for java spring? The tutorials I go through, their structure is like this/

```java
src
 -test
 -main
   -java
   -resources
   -config
   -webapp
      -frontend
          -META-INF
          -WEB-INF
              -web.xml
```

Can I change name, for example `webapp` -> `js`? If I do, should I have to edit configuration somewhere?

If I am allowed to change it, is configuration different between Spring and Spring Boot?
**EDIT**
I am using maven, so @Nathan mentioned it is maven naming convention. If I change the name of directory, how does maven find out? Should I have to add in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: those are maven naming conventions. if you don't have to change it don't.

Comment: @NathanHughes should I have to change `pom.xml`, if I want to change name of the folder?

Comment: @Kayaman I was curious that how Spring or Maven takes care of name changes. Like, how they reflect it in their configuration files (ex. `pom` or `web.xml`). This question may not be useful for you though.

Comment: The question isn't very useful if it's only to satisfy your curiosity, as there's no reason for you to change the name, or is there? It certainly wouldn't make sense to change it to `js`, as it might give the wrong impression that it contains only javascript files.

Comment: to see how to override naming conventions start here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html